# how do i verify a booking with an admin account using acts_as_state_machine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i have a booking model which other users make bookings, but i want to allow the admin to verify first the booking then it will appear in the index, how can i achieve that goal? i already have admin account setup, just the verification.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM
  aasm do
    state :unverified, initial: true
    state :verified
    event :verify do
      transitions from: [:unverified], to: :verified
    end
  end
  belongs_to :town
  private
end
```

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :destory]
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:destory]

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "we have recieved your booking, we'll communicate shortly"
      render 'new'
    else
      flash[:error] = "please fill all fields"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @booking.update(booking_params)
      flash[:success] = "your booking has been sent, we'll call you as soon as we find a house that matches"
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      flash[:error] = "please fill all fields"
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @booking.destroy
      flash[:success] = "your booking was successfully cancelled"
      redirect_to rentals_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong with your cancellation request, try again"
      redirect_to @booking
    end
  end

  private

  def set_booking
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:name, :phone, :town_id, :location, :rooms, :rent, :info, :user_id)
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_for @booking do |f| %>
  <div>
        <br>
        <select name="booking[town_id]">
            <% Town.all.each do |town| %>
                <option value="<%= town.id %>"><%= town.name %></option>
            <% end %>
        </select>
        <select name="booking[state]">// i tried this but it brings up an error //
            <% Booking.states.each do |state| %>
                <option value="<%= booking.state %>"><%= booking.state %></option>
            <% end %>
        </select>
        <%= options_for_select(@booking.states_for_select, selected: @booking.state, disabled: @booking.impossible_states) %>//also i tried this but it brings up an error //

      
        <%= f.submit "send"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

i have looked at the docs most of it talks about automated states but for me i want an admin to do verify manually. any guides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AASM generates automatic scopes for each state, so you can only list verified bookings by using the following:

```
Booking.verified
```

And to verify a booking by an admin, all you need to call the following method on a `Booking` object.

```
booking.verify!
```

So, to achieve what you need, you have to modify the `index` action to filter bookings, and you have to add another action `verify` that's responsible for verifying bookings.

Modify the `bookings_controller` as following:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  # ... 
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy, :verify]
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy, :verify]
  # ... 

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.verified
  end

  def verify
    @booking.verify!
    # you may add more logic here, such as setting flash messages and redirections. 
  end
  # ... 
end
```

In `routes.rb` you have to define the `verify`'s action route.